# How to select/multiselect cells of a heatmap and download excel file in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6, heatmap

I am implementing data visualization with syncfusion angular heat map in
 which each cell represents the no of counts of some records which lies in that
 cell according to some criteria .My task is to implement click event on any of the cells and
 download and excel file which can give the details of those records.

```html
<ejs-heatmap 
    height ="700" 
    id='container' 
    style="display:block;" 
    [cellSettings]='cellSettings' 
    showTooltip='true' 
    style="display:block;" 
    [titleSettings]='titleSettings' 
    [dataSource]='dataSource' 
    [xAxis]='xAxis' 
    [yAxis]='yAxis' 
    (cellSelected)=exportAsXLSX($event) 
    [allowSelection]= 'true' 
    [legendSettings]='legendSettings'> 
</ejs-heatmap>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I edited your question and added the code you commented. next time, please edit your question and include all the details there.

Comment: FYI you have two `style` attributes. Seems that you've tried using `(cellSelected)=exportAsXLSX($event)`, is it called?